# Align = center - 200px?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with this configuration:

```
<table width = "100%" border = "0" align = "center">
  <tr>
    <td width = "200px" align = "center"></td>
    <td align = "center"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Because the first column causes the data in column to to be offset from the center by 200px, is it possible to use some calculation, whether it be for CSS, or possibly, HTML, to center the content in column 2 and then move it to the left 200px to compensate for column 1's width?

Comment: Do you want the content within the table cell to be shifted 200px left of center?

Comment: `align="center"` is deprecated. Use CSS instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<table width = "100%" border = "0" align = "center">
  <tr>
    <td width = "200px" align = "center">test</td>
    <td align = "center"><div style="margin-left:-200px;">test</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Ex: http://jsfiddle.net/DrSDr/2/